# Streams,Buffer in Java

Tags: java

I have exams in java and when I study I saw this exercise and I try to solve it but I found some difficulty so please help me
Consider the following comment, header and partial code for a method in a utility
encryption class called Atbash.

```
    /**
    * Prompts the user for the pathname of a source .txt file to encrypt.
    * Prompts the user for the pathname of a destination .txt file
    * to which the encrypted text will be written.
    * The pathnames are then used to create two File objects.
    * The method then attempts to open streams on both files, one to
    * read from the source file, the other to write to the destination file.
    *
    * The method then reads from the read stream a line at a time.
    * Each line read is converted to uppercase using the message
    * toUpperCase(). The method then constructs an encrypted string
    * into which all the alphabetic characters from the line are
    • substituted by their atbash equivalent, however any numeric or
    * punctuation characters are simply added unchanged to the encrypted
    * string. After each string is constructed it is written to the write
    * stream followed by a newline character.
    */
    public static void encryptFile()
    {
    OUDialog.alert("Please choose a file to encrypt");
    String pathname = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
    File aFile = new File(pathname);
    OUDialog.alert("Please give a file name for the encrypted file");
    String pathname2 = OUFileChooser.getFilename();
    File bFile = new File(pathname2);
    BufferedReader bufferedFileReader = null;
    BufferedWriter bufferedFileWriter = null;

    try
    {
    String currentLine;
    bufferedFileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(aFile));
    bufferedFileWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(bFile));
    String codedLine = "";
    char currentChar;
    String alphabet ="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    String mirror ="ZYXWVUTSRQPONMLKJIHGFEDCBA";
    currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine();
    while (//Boolean condition to be written as your answer for part (i))
/**this what I do while(currentLine!=null)*/

    {
    //Statement block to be written as your answer for part (ii)

    }
    }
    catch (Exception anException)
    {
    System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
    }
    finally
    {
    try
    {
    //Statement block to be written as your answer for part (iii)
  /* bufferedFileReader.close();
   *  bufferedFileWriter.close();
   */

    }
    catch (Exception anException)
    {
    System.out.println("Error: " + anException);
    }
    }
    }
```

(i) Write down the boolean condition for the while loop in the above method.

```
while(currentLine= bufferedFileReader.readLine()!= null)
    {

    }
```

(ii) Write the code for the while statement block in the above method. This should
ensure that when the while loop has terminated, the destination .txt file contains
an encrypted version of the source .txt file. Your code should make use of the
variables bufferedFileReader, bufferedFileWriter, currentLine, codedLine,
currentChar, alphabet and mirror.
You may find the following two messages from the protocol of String useful:
charAt(int) which returns the char value at the index specified by the argument
and indexOf(char) which returns the index of the first occurrence of the
argument within the receiver.

(iii) Write the code for the final try block.

```
bufferedFileReader.close();
 bufferedFileWriter.close();
```

Comment: Smells like homework... if so, please tag it accordingly. Show us what you have tried so far, and where you are stuck - otherwise your post will get closed quickly. We won't do your homework for you, but are happy to help if we see that you have done your fair share of effort.

Comment: Nice homework how about tagging it as such?

Comment: I guess your question is if someone wants to do your homework?

Comment: Added homework tag based on the updated content of the post.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
/**this what I do while(currentLine!=-1)*/
```

since `currentLine` is a `String`, you can't compare it to an `int` value. You should check the Javadoc of [`BufferedReader.readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) to see how it indicates that there is no more data to read, then fix the condition accordingly.

Comment: I used ReadLine()to reads a whole line of the file and returns a string.

Comment: @user527619, yes, and what does it return when there is no more data to read?

Comment: @user527619, exactly :-) with one caveat: putting an assignment into a condition makes your code less readable and may cause subtle bugs, so you should at least use brackets: `((currentLine = bufferedFileReader.readLine()) != null)`. I would actually prefer extracting the assignment into a separate line though: `currentLine= bufferedFileReader.readLine(); while (currentLine != null) ...`

Comment: @Péter: I agree about the brackets, but have always disagreed in principle with extracting the assignment out of the condition because that requires duplicating the assignment: Once before the loop and an identical assignment at the end of the loop.  IIRC, this duplication form was known as the "Read Ahead" technique when I studied programming; in languages like C where the assignment can be embedded in the condition test it violates DRY, which IMHO is the more important consideration.

Comment: @Peter: But still, +1, for a good answer to a terrible question.

Comment: @Software Monkey, I tend to prefer readability over DRY in this case, but I am not religious about it. Now that you made me think of it, this is indeed a remnant from school days :-)

Comment: @Péter: I would normally, also; but I have been burned multiple times over the years by changing one read and not the other, while I have never been burned by having the assignment embedded.  Also, in some ways, embedding the assign is *more* readable, again IMHO.